# Windows 10 - Shell commands for CTRL+Alt+Del not working

Tags: windows, security, password, windows-command-prompt, password-reset

We have an icon with a target path of "**explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}**" which pulls up Windows Security window in order for users to select change password from an RDP session.

Well we are also attempting to use this same icon locally so users don't have to know **Crtl+alt+del** or **ctrl+alt+end** etc...

Though when a local user (meaning one that is connected to the console session and not RDP'd in) attempts to use the shortcut. Nothing happens.

I've tried both options here, but neither launch.

With an admin account and a standard user account if I'm at the machine on a console session it won't work.

I'm guessing it has to do with executing a "SHell" command locally, but I just can't find anything to solve this.

```
Powershell -noprofile -nologo -noninteractive -command “(new-object -ComObject shell.application).WindowsSecurity()”
```

or from explorer:

```
explorer.exe shell:::{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can't be about executing `explorer.exe shell:::{CLSID}` locally, as

- Other GUID's works, e.g. `{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}` for *All Control Panel Items*.
- Alternative methods like `explorer /e,::{CLSID}` aren't working with `{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}` for *Windows Security*, either.

This is probably by design, as it's much more secure to make the users press Ctrl-Alt-Del first. In 2020, this key combination should be common knowledge, whereas Ctrl-Alt-End for RDP is less known.